# Chrome scroll dissapears when hidding modal and showing another modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've run into an anoying "bug" which I can't seem to find the solution for.

In bootstrap you are only able to show one modal at a time. So through an open modal (scrollbar in chrome is there) I click a button which opens another modal just after i hide the first modal. Like this:

```
$('#redigerMedarbejder').modal('hide'); 
$('#uploadModal').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: false})
```

When I close the open modal and do there reverse of the code above, to show the previous modal again, my scrollbar in chrome disappears and I'm not able to see the entire modal as i cannot scroll. I've seen others suggest to override the modal.open style like this

```
.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

But that does not seem to do the trick...

Comment: @TimLewis You are a genius :) ... Please put that into an answer and remove the comment .. i will accept it as an answer . thanks a lot

Comment: @TimLewis The other way around with the modals (just to clarify) but YES it is luckily also my intention, as that modal can only be opened from the other modal... :)

Comment: @TimLewis although the uploadModal is used across other pages of my site, but that does not create a problem (just tested)

Comment: @TimLewis There is one tiny issue though.. The scroll wheel on the mouse does not seem to be able to scroll my modal after the trick .. It might not think that there is scrollable content ? .. im not sure ..

Comment: Yeah, the scroll-wheel functionality is bizarre. I've see that issue before in Chrome, but if you test in another browser (like Firefox) you shouldn't see that issue. I'll add the answer btw, just a second :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger a modal and have it work properly after another modal is closed, you have to (should) wait until the first one is completely hidden with the event `hidden.bs.modal`:

```
$('#redigerMedarbejder').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    $('#uploadModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
});
```

Small caveat, this `.on('hidden.bs.modal')` function will be called **every time** the `$('#redigerMedarbejder')` is hidden, so bear that in mind when using this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question.And I solve it by adding "modal-open" to the class of body when I hide a modal. Here's the code:

```
$('#redigerMedarbejder').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e){
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
});
```

I found that the class "modal-open" will add to `<body></body>` when you open a modal and remove when you close it.